# Polar System with Short Answers, How $U(0, \theta)=\pi$ will be calculated?

Tags: linear-algebra, education, laplace-transform, polar-coordinates, laplacian

I read some notes on Laplace. I ran into a short answer question as follows.

We have a Laplace equation in Polar Systems:

### $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \theta^2} $

with boundary conditions:

$u(a,\theta)=\begin{cases}2\theta & 0<\theta<\pi\\0 & \pi<\theta<2\pi\end{cases}$

then the value of $U(0, \theta)=\pi$.

My Challenge is How this value will be reached? I found $U(0, \theta)=2\pi$. Any Ideas?